# How to show in Django Admin the list of Activities a user has made

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the most out of my Django Blog project and wanted to know how to show in the admin the activities that a user has made like making comments or giving likes to posts.

I need some hints and guidance on how to add this information in the admin.py

**Here is the models.py in Blog App**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=120)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Blog Posts'

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post}-{self.user}-Comment No.{self.pk}"

LIKE_CHOICES = (
    ('Like', 'Like'),
    ('Unlike', 'Unlike')
)


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, max_length=8)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post}-{self.user}-{self.value}"
```

**Here is the models.py in Users App**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

**This is what I have tried in the models.py in Users app but didn't work**

```
    # Get the no. of posts
    def get_posts_no(self):
        return self.author.all().count()
    # Get the no. of likes
    def get_likes_given(self):
        likes= set.like_set.all()
        total_liked=0
        for item in likes:
            if item.value=='Like':
                total_liked+=1
        return total_liked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"... to add this information in the admin.py" → do you mean to say that you would like to show an additional column in the Django admin site with said information? If so, then the answer is:

In your admin.py, extend the PostAdmin class with a custom queryset and add `comments_count` and `likes_count` to `list_display = (...)`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Count
from .models import Post


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'date_posted', 'comments_count', 'likes_count')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            _comments_count=Count('comment_set', distinct=True),
            _likes_count=Count('like_set', distinct=True)
        )
        return queryset

    def comments_count(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, '_comments_count'):
            return obj._comments_count
        return None

    def likes_count(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, '_likes_count'):
            return obj._likes_count
        return None

    comments_count.admin_order_field = '_comments_count'
    likes_count.admin_order_field = '_likes_count'


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Comment: @LuckasKlement I am getting `Cannot resolve keyword 'comment_set' into field.` error

Comment: but what I was trying to achieve is get the details related to each user activity, like how many a like did a user give and how many comment a user made not the no. of like and comments per post

Comment: You can add an explicit related name to address this issue: add the argument related_name='post_comments' and related_name='post_likes' respectively to the "post" foreign key fields on the Comment and Like model. Then, replace 'comment_set' with 'post_comments' and 'like_set' with 'post_likes'.